# Model View Controller in Qt application development

Tags: c++, qt, model-view-controller

What is the point behind the MVC pattern? When it is recommended to use MVC design pattern when designing application, what type of applications? I am using Qt for half a year, and never used MVC, whether I should use it? What other design patterns exist for application design and development?

Comment: It's almost impossible to use Qt w/o using model-view architecture as Qt kinda forces you to.

Comment: If you have read a book or an article on MVC and you don't understand, or disaree with, a specific point in it, quote that specific point. Otherwise the question is not specific enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[MVC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) is the more usual design pattern for the core of GUI applications.
The main purpose, like a lot of architecture, is to split logic and data in your code, because it's more easy to read, maintain (you'll find a lot of advantages)...

But there is something a little more specific. MVC standard is to use [Observer/Observable](http://www.oodesign.com/observer-pattern.html) pattern, to refresh your views only when your data are updated. Not like a game loop.

About Qt (>= 4.0), you can see [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/model-view-programming.html), that MVC is a part of the framework architecture. So you already use it : don't try to reimplement it, just use Qt classes like it was design (see the link above).

You can also extend the architecture with some MVC variant like [MVVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93viewmodel), [PureMVC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PureMVC)....

About other architectures, I love [Entity Component System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity_component_system) but it's a little too much for small applications. If you want too learn more about Design Pattern in general, this [site](http://www.oodesign.com/) is a good one (maybe a little old).

Comment: So signals and slots are part of MVC?

Comment: @Lazar Signals and slots can be used to help implment MVC, but they stand on their own. They are a "part" of MVC as long as you're thinking of a particular implementation of MVC done using Qt.

Comment: Check the link in my answer (about Qt MVC), and search signal and slot keyword. You'll know everything you need. But yes Qt MVC integrate signals and slots in their design (I don't say that you need signals and slots to design your own MVC).

Answer (score 0):

[MVC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) is a pattern used for GUI applications: it ensures that your business logic -  within the [M]odel - is separated from your GUI - within the [V]iews. The [C]ontroller makes sure that those two can communicate with each other.

One of the biggest advantages of this decoupling is that your application will stay maintainable. I can tell you from personal experience that applications with one main dialog handling almost everything (db access, user input verification, etc.) are really hard to maintain. Do yourself a favor and stick to clean architectures within your applications as this will pay off later within its life cycle.

Another GUI application pattern would be [MVVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93viewmodel) and for more information on the topic of application patterns I highly recommend the book "Patterns of Enterprise Application Architecture" by Martin Fowler.

Answer (score 0):

Qt makes extensive use of it's own model/view pattern throughout the QtGUI components which is it's interpretation of the MVC pattern.

See here for more details:

http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/modelview.html

When should you use it? Ideally wherever possible - especially when dealing with complex GUI components that need to represent large quantities of data. The QTableView is where I make use of it most regularly.

The main advantage it gives you is simple, by loosely coupling your view and your data, changes to one have minimal impact on the other. This makes your code more maintainable in the future.